# Cómo almacenar el resultado de una consulta con javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema, no sé como obtener el valor de una consulta de la base de datos. Hice este código pero no muestra nada.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">

   <input type="hidden" name="idArticulo" 
      id="idArticulo<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?>"
      value="<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?> "/>

    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" 
      value="1" />

    <span id="Info"></span> <!-- muestra el mensaje-->

</div> <!--end class="col-lg-2" -->
```

Código java script es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*--manda a llamar al input <quantity> --*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#quantity').blur(function() {
            $('#Info').html('<img src="img/gif/load.gif" alt="">').fadeOut(1000);

            var product_id              = $(this).attr("id");
            var product_quantity        = $('#quantity').val();

            $.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                url: 'php/stock.php',
                data:{  
                    product_id:       product_id,   
                    product_quantity: product_quantity
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#Info').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

El código php

```
        <?php
          sleep(1);
          include_once '../connections/conexion.php';
          if($_REQUEST) {

           if(isset($_POST['product_quantity']) && ($_POST['product_id'])) {

            $product_id =         $_REQUEST['product_id'];
            $product_quantity =   $_REQUEST['product_quantity'];

            $stock   = $ConexionBD->query("SELECT unidadesExistentes FROM articulo 
                        WHERE idArticulo = '$product_id' ");

            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stock)) {
                //aqui es donde quiero almacenar el valor en la variable
                $variable = $rows['unidadesExistentes'];
                echo $variable;

            }

        } //end isset

        if($stock < $product_quantity ){
            echo '<div id="Error">Sin stock</div>';
        }else {
            echo '<div id="Error">Ok,Disponible</div>';
            echo 'Teclee: '.$product_quantity;

        }

    } //

end REQUEST
?>
```

Comment: ¿Has mirado que los datos te lleguen correctamente al PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto, era que no estaba mandando a llamar el input `idArticulo`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*----*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#quantity').blur(function() {
            $('#Info').html('<img src="img/gif/load.gif" alt="">').fadeOut(1000);

            var product_id              = $('#idArticulo').val(); //Aqui esta la modificacion
            var product_quantity        = $('#quantity').val();

            $.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                url: 'php/stock.php',
                data:{  
                    product_id:       product_id,   
                    product_quantity: product_quantity
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#Info').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

y en el php lo tengo de esta manera

```
<?php
sleep(1);
include_once '../connections/conexion.php';
if($_REQUEST) {

if(isset($_POST['product_quantity']) && ($_POST['product_id'])) {

    $product_id =         $_REQUEST['product_id'];
    $product_quantity =   $_REQUEST['product_quantity'];

    $stock   = $ConexionBD->query("SELECT unidadesExistentes FROM articulo 
                WHERE idArticulo = '$product_id' ");

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stock)) {
        $valor = $rows['unidadesExistentes'];
        echo $valor; //ahora si imprime :)

        if($valor < $product_quantity ){
            echo '<div id="Error">Sin stock</div>';
        }else {
            echo '<div id="Error">Ok,Disponible</div>';
            echo 'Teclee: '.$product_quantity;

        }
    }

} //end isset



} //end REQUEST
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando  *mysqli_fetch_array($result)* lo cual significa que trabajarás con arreglos los cuales, como sabes, se trabajan mediante *index*. Entonces, cuando usas  `mysqli_fetch_array` en vez de pasarle *$variable["nombreColumna"]* tienes que pasarle el index:

```
$variable[0]
```

Para usar el código que ya tienes implementado debería funcionar si cambias:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($stock)
```

Por esta:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($stock, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Donde **MYSQLI_ASSOC** es un segundo parámetros opcional de *mysqli_fetch_array* 
 que indica la manera en que se manejarán tus resultados (puede ser *MYSQLI_NUM*, *MYSQLI_ASSOC* o *MYSQLI_BOTH*). 
Con *MYSQLI_ASSOC* le estás indicando que trabajarás por nombres asociativos y no por arreglos. Si quieres trabajarlo con ambos el parámetro a pasarle es *MYSQLI_BOTH*

**Adicionalmente**

En tu código estás trabajando al principio orientado a objetos:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Por lo tanto, la manera en que en teoría deberías manejar la información es así:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

La manera en la que tú estás obteniendo la información es por procedimientos y la conexión y ejecución de la consulta se haría así:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Para más información favor de visitar [mysqli_fetch_array del manual de PHP.](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)